# Using information from an external file, How can I fill my array up correctly using fread?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I need to be able to make sure my array is correctly receiving values from the file card.raw through fread.

I am not confident about using arrays with pointers, so if anybody could help me with the theory here, it would be GREATLY appreciate it.  Thanks in advance.

The code is supposed to take literally one block of size 512 bytes and stick it into the array.  Then I am just using a debugger and printf to examine the arrays output.

```
/**
 * recover.c
 *
 * Computer Science 50
 * Problem Set 4
 *
 * Recovers JPEGs from a forensic image.
 */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

    //Size of EACH FAT JPEG in bytes    
    #define FILESIZE 512   

    unsigned char* buffer[FILESIZE];

    ///Step 1: Open jpeg
    FILE* readfrom = fopen("card.raw", "rb");
    if (readfrom == NULL)
    {
        printf("Could not open");
    }

    ///Step 2: Find Beginning of JPEG.  The first digits will be 255216255 Then 224 or 225
    fread(&buffer, FILESIZE, 1, readfrom);
    for(int x = 0; x < FILESIZE; x++)
    {
        printf("%d = %c\n", x,  buffer[x]);
    }

    fclose(readfrom);
}
```

Comment: What happens when you run this code?  Do you get any errors?  You can edit your question to add this information.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use return values from input functions.  `fread()` reports how many elements were read - code might not have read 512.  Swap `FILESIZE, 1` to detect the number of characters/bytes read.

   ```
   // fread(&buffer, FILESIZE, 1, readfrom);
   size_t count = fread(&buffer, 1, FILESIZE, readfrom);
   ```
2. Only print out up to the number of elements read.  Recommend hexadecimal (and maybe decimal) output rather than character.

   ```
   for(size_t x = 0; x < count; x++) {
     // printf("%d = %c\n", x,  buffer[x]);
     printf("%3zu = %02X % 3u\n", x, buffer[x], buffer[x]);
   }
   ```
3. If the `fopen()` failed, best to not continue with `for()` and `fclose()`.

   ```
   if (readfrom == NULL) {
     printf("Could not open");
     return -1;
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

The second parameter is **size, in bytes, of each element to be read.**
The third parameter is **Number of elements each one with a size of the <second parameter> bytes.**
So, swap your second and first parameters.

Replace `unsigned char* buffer[FILESIZE];` with `unsigned char buffer[FILESIZE];`. For now, you have an array of `unsigned char *`, when you need `unsigned char`. Because buffer is already a pointer, you **don't need to take its address.** In `fread` call, replace `&buffer` with `buffer`.

It must go like this: `fread(buffer, 1, FILESIZE, readfrom);`

One more thing: add `return` with a specific error code after `printf("Could not open");`, because if file hasn't been open, you cannot read from it, can you? And add `return 0;` in the end of `main`.

And take your `#define` out of `main`.

Read more about `fread` here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fread/

Comment: Thanks for your help.  Could you clarify why buffer is already a pointer?

Comment: @Jordan Fitzmichael Kennedy when you declare an array like this: int ar[N], ar has the following type: const int *

Comment: @JordanFitzmichaelKennedy yes, and `fread` wants `void*` as the first parameter. If you pass `buffer` like this: `fread(buffer, 1, FILESIZE, readfrom);`, it will be implicitly converted to `void*`